# Decomposition of tensor product by Clebsh-Gordan rule

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras, tensor-products

Let $V_n$ be an irreducible representation of Lie algebra $sl_2$ (  or $su(2)$). Then by Clebsh-Gordan rule,  we have the following decomposition of the tensor product:
$$
V_n \otimes V_m=V_{n+m}+V_{n+m-2}+\cdots+V_{n-m}, n \geq m.
$$
By hand, I can perform  the  decomposition for $3$ factors, for example 
$$
V_4 \otimes V_3 \otimes V_2=V_{9}+2 V_{7}+3 V_5+3 V_3+ 2 V_1,
$$
but for more factors seems  it is a hard problem.

**Question.** Is there any exact expression for the multiplicities  $\mu_1, \mu_2, \ldots$ in the tensor product decomposition
$$
V_{k_1} \otimes V_{k_2} \otimes \cdots  V_{k_n}=V_{k_1+k_2+\cdots+k_n}+\mu_1 V_{k_1+k_2+\cdots+k_n-1} +\mu_2 V_{k_1+k_2+\cdots+k_n-2} + \cdots
$$

Comment: In the language of symmetric functions, you are asking for the coefficient of the Schur function $s_{\left(i, j\right)}$ in the decomposition of a complete homogeneous symmetric function $h_{\left(k_1, k_2, \ldots, k_n\right)}$ in the Schur basis. This is precisely the scalar product $\left( h_{\left(k_1, k_2, \ldots, k_n\right)}, s_{\left(i, j\right)}\right)$, or, equivalently, the coefficient of the monomial $x_1^{k_1} x_2^{k_2} \cdots x_n^{k_n}$ in the Schur function $s_{\left(i, j\right)}$. But this is the number of semistandard tableaux of shape $\left(i, j\right)$ with ...

Comment: ... content $\left(k_1, k_2, \ldots, k_n\right)$. Not sure if this can be made more explicit.

Comment: Ah, you could also try to find that coefficient by using the Jacobi-Trudi identity in the form $s_{\left(i, j\right)} = h_i h_j - h_{i+1} h_{j-1}$. This looks somewhat painful but simpler.

Comment: Thank you..any reference, please

Comment: Also, seems the complete homogeneous symmetric function appears in  the symmetric powers decomposition, not for tensor product, am I right?

Comment: Oh, I'm afraid you are right: the characters of the $V_i$ are not the $h_i$. Sorry!

Comment: the character of $V_i$ is Schur function $\frac{x^{n+1}-x^{-(n+1)}}{x-x^{-1}}$

Comment: @Leox: As you pointed out, the character of $V_n$ is the quantum integer $[n+1]$, and the problem you're describing is equivalent to expressing a product $[k_1][k_2]\cdots[k_n]$ of quantum integers as a linear combination of quantum integers. I guess you might find more explicit formulae by searching around for this?

Comment: @Joppy, So far I can't find out  such a formulae